# sequential and parallel execution of map reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am quite new to Hadoop and  need help in below scenario. Let us say  have 5 MR jobs

```
  P1(MR1+ MR2 ) -->// MR1 and MR2 run sequentially



P2(MR3+MR4)// // MR3 and MR4 run sequentially

and P1 and P2 run parallel way .Output of P1 and P2 will be joined By MR5.
```

How do I defined this kind of complex work flow in hadoop?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at Oozie if you have more complex requirements : [Oozie](https://oozie.apache.org/)

For simple requirements you can use Dependency Management in the Job API.